# Gitlab: how can I disable email notifications for new commits pushed to merge requests?

Tags: git, gitlab

In Gitlab my notification settings are set to "participate". I am getting tons of emails from Gitlab.

I would like to receive emails regarding new *comments* on merge requests that I'm participating in. But I would not like to receive an email for every time somebody pushes a *commit* to an MR that is assigned to me. That results in a huge amount of emails that I simply ignore.

I also wouldn't mind getting an email notification for a commit pushed on a merge request *opened* by me, but that's just a nice to have.

Looking in the Gitlab notification settings I haven't found a setting to support this. "Custom" settings are simply an extension of "particiapte", which means I still get an email for every little thing that happens on an MR I'm participating in (i.e., every commit). Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it's something better to be filtered on your email client side. Is it an option for you?

Comment: @fluffy Yep, I guess that can work :)

Comment: For reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#filtering-email Please share the answer if you can figure it out :)

Comment: @Stefan_EOX, yes, theoretically this _should_ work. Practically it doesn't. I set both the global _and_ the repo-level notifications to "Disabled", and I still get notifications e.g. when adding a new SSH key, logging in from another machine etc. Smells like a silly bug.